# delete record from mysql using php by comparing data in coloumn

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to delete a record from database and I am using this code.

```
 $value = $_POST['name'];
 $sql="DELETE FROM savedemail WHERE email='$value'";
```

This code is deleting records. But with the indexes like if I enter 3 it deletes the record of third row not by matching the content of the database.

I want to delete a record by matching the data inside the column with my given $values variable.

Comment: This query can't delete third row of a table. Unless email in this row is `3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `LIKE`

```
$sql="DELETE FROM savedemail WHERE serial LIKE '%$value%'";
```

So if `$value` is equal to `blah` then it will delete all the rows that contain the word `blah`.  The `blah` could be anywhere inside of the serial column field.

Read more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html

> Pattern Matching
>
> [..] “%” to match an arbitrary number of characters [..]
>
> To find names containing a “w”:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT * FROM pet WHERE name LIKE '%w%';
> +----------+-------+---------+------+------------+------------+
> | name     | owner | species | sex  | birth      | death      |
> +----------+-------+---------+------+------------+------------+
> | Claws    | Gwen  | cat     | m    | 1994-03-17 | NULL       |
> | Bowser   | Diane | dog     | m    | 1989-08-31 | 1995-07-29 |
> | Whistler | Gwen  | bird    | NULL | 1997-12-09 | NULL       |
> +----------+-------+---------+------+------------+------------+
> ```